# If you have a vector with repeated numerical data, determine which is the prime that is repeated the most

Tags: python, list, for-loop

If you have a vector with repeated numerical data, determine which is the prime that is repeated the most.

You are not allowed to use build-in python functions like sort...and also dictionaries-sets and tuples are not allowed

I was trying:

```html
cd = int(input("enter the quantity of data: "))
v = []
vp = []
for i in range(cd):
    v.append(int(input("input an elment: ")))

for j in range(cd):
    m = 0
    for x in range(v[j]):
        if v[j] % x == 0:
            m += 1
    if m == 2:
        vp.append(v[j])

for k in range(len(vp)):
    for s in range(1,vp):
        if vp[k] == vp[s]:
            sp = sp + 1
```

but failed

Comment: _. . .but failed_ This doesn't tell us anything.  How, specifically, did it fail?  Did you get an error?  Did you get unexpected results?  Did you get no results at all?  In other words, you need to **show us what the code did**, and **explain what you wanted instead**.

Comment: It *must* me telling you something like  `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero` with an error pointing to the exact line of code. Is there something about that error you don't understand?

Comment: @Mark that error is easy to fix I mean the whole algorithm how can I complete the algorithm or how would you do it

Comment: If that error is easy for you to fix, I would suggest fixing it. Once it's running head over to [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and ask about ways to improve the working code. There's no sense posting code with easy-to-fix errors and saying nothing more than 'it failed' if you are looking for ways to improve.

Comment: @Mark the algorithm is unfinished